# Python. VK. access_token

Tags: python, вконтакте

В библиотеке VK есть метод авторизации пользователя по его токену (access_token):

```
session = vk.Session(access_tokenMy)
api = vk.API(session
```

В принципе возможно создать чат-бота со своей страницы, хотя капча подпортит малину. Но вопрос в другом - возможно ли получить access_token на основе введённого ЛОГИНА и ПАРОЛЯ программным способом на Python? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

В той же самой библиотеке VK есть [AuthSession](https://vk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#vk-authsession), который позволяет авторизовать пользователя через логин и пароль.

```py
import vk

session = vk.AuthSession(app_id=42, user_login="login", user_password="password")
api = vk.API(session)
```

Если так необходимо получить именно `access_token`, то нужно вызвать `session.get_access_token()`